# Not able transfer multiple file though inputted correct path

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, winscp

Not able transfer multiple file though inputted correct path

```
######Transfer file
Write-Host ("Start script.")
try
{
    $todaysDate = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Add-Type -Path "D:\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
 
    # Setup session options
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    $SessionOptions.Timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 90
    $sessionOptions.HostName = "hostname"
    $sessionOptions.UserName = "username"
    $sessionOptions.PortNumber = "portnumber"
    $sessionOptions.Password = ""
    $sessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = "D:\privatekey" 
    $sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxx"
    
    #Write-Host ("Connecting.")    
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    $session.SessionLogPath = "D:\WinSCPSessionLog_$todaysDate.log"
 
   #Upload files
    try
    {
      # Connect
      $session.Open($sessionOptions)
      
      #File list:
      Write-Host ("File list: ")
      
      #transferoptions
      $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
      #$transferOptions.FileMask = "*.*"
      $transferOptions.FilePermissions = $Null # This is default
      $transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $False # if Timestamp on file is enable      
      
      $localPath = Get-ChildItem "D:\dq\*.csv" | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::today)}
      $remotePath = "/Outbox/"
      
      # Upload files, collect results
      $transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions)
        
      # Upload files, collect results
      #$transferResult = $session.PutFiles(($localPath + "*.*"), ($remotePath, + "*.*") $False, $transferOptions).Check()
        
      # Iterate over every transfer
      foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
      {
         # Success or error?
         if ($transfer.Error -eq $Null)
         {
            #$transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions).Check()
            Write-Host ("Upload of {0} succeeded, moving to save" -f $transfer.FileName)    
         }
         else
         {
            Write-Host ("Upload of {0} failed: {1}" -f $transfer.FileName, $transfer.Error.Message)
         }
      }
      #End of files:
      Write-Host ("End of files. ")      
    }
    finally
    {
      # Disconnect, clean up
      $session.Dispose()
      Write-Host ("Disconnected.")      
    }
 
    #exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $todaysDate = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Set-Content -Path "D:\WinSCPError_$todaysDate.log" $_.Exception.Message
    #exit 1
}
```

Log File:

File list:
Upload of D:\dq\ADD.csv D:\dq\MINUS.csv D:\dq\DIVIDE.csv failed: File or folder 'D:\dq\ADD.csv D:\dq\MINUS.csv D:\dq\DIVIDE.csv' does not exist.
System Error.  Code: 123.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Error:

1. not able transfer file due to file not exists. I have inputted correct

Tools:

1. Using superb old version of .NET
2. Using superb old version of window server

Expected result:

1. able transfer multiple files in "D:\dq*.csv" and the file modified date must be today's date

Comment: The winscp docs state the localPath argument should be a "Full path to local file or directory to upload. Filename in the path can be replaced with Windows wildcard1 to select multiple files". You can't pass _multiple_ paths at once

Answer (score 0):

> I have inputted correct

Nope, you haven't. From the [WinSCP documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles) for the `localPath` argument:

> Full path to local file or directory to upload. Filename in the path can be replaced with Windows wildcard1 to select multiple files. To upload all files in a directory, use mask *.

That is, it expects *one path*, not multiple.

Given your requirement for filtering on `LastWriteTime`, passing `"D:\dq\*.csv"` as the argument is not a viable option, so the solution is to upload the files one-by-one:

```
# ...
try{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    
    #File list:
    Write-Host ("File list: ")
    
    #transferoptions
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    #$transferOptions.FileMask = "*.*"
    $transferOptions.FilePermissions = $Null # This is default
    $transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $False # if Timestamp on file is enable

    # Loop through each relevant file
    foreach($localFile in Get-ChildItem "D:\dq\*.csv" | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::today)}){
        $remotePath = "/Outbox/"
        # Upload files, collect results
        $transferResult = $session.PutFileToDirectory($localFile.FullName, $remotePath, $false, $transferOptions)
                
        # Success or error?
        if ($transferResult.Error -eq $Null) {
            #$transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions).Check()
            Write-Host ("Upload of {0} succeeded, moving to save" -f $transferResult.FileName)    
        }
        else {
            Write-Host ("Upload of {0} failed: {1}" -f $transferResult.FileName, $transferResult.Error.Message)
        }
    }
}
finally{
    # ...
}
```

Comment: tried method as provided, the script hanging and unable send files to winscp server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Martias is correct. You cannot pass multiple paths to [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles).

But you can let WinSCP itself pick the today's `*.csv` files with just two lines of code, using [`todays` constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#today).

Using [`Session.PutFilesToDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfilestodirectory) would also make the code somewhat simpler.

```
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
# (your other transfer options)

$transferOptions.FileMask = ">=today"

$transferResult =
    $session.PutFilesToDirectory(
        $localPath, $remotePath, "*.csv", $False, $transferOptions).Check()
```

Comment: $todaysDate = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')

$transferOptions.FileMask = $todaysDate

$transferResult = $session.PutFileToDirectory($localPath, $remotePath, "*.csv", $False, $transferOptions).Check()
log i get as below. suspect server too old (using 2008)
Method invocation failed because [WinSCP.Session] doesn't contain a method named 'PutFileToDirectory'.

Comment: You are using an old version of the .NET assembly. Upgrade to the latest version. Also this is wrong: `$transferOptions.FileMask = $todaysDate`. If you want to do it this way, it must be `$transferOptions.FileMask = ">=" + $todaysDate` – But why? The `today` works.

Comment: too bad, i cant use latest version of .NET assembly until next year. maybe the only way i can do compressed all file into zip folder then send the zip folder to another destination

Comment: OK, there's no problem with using the `PutFiles` for this: `$transferResult = $session.PutFiles("D:\dq\*.csv", $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions).Check()`

Comment: Noted. But in the dq folder consists of old files, so i need the files with today's date.

Comment: Come on! That's what `$transferOptions.FileMask = ">=today"` does.

Comment: thanks, it's work.. however, i tried $transferOptions.FileMask = ">=$todaysDate" and it's working.. tested both >=$todaysDate" and ">="+$todaysDate and ">="+$todaysDate is faster...

Comment: Yes `$transferOptions.FileMask = ">=$todaysDate"` works, I wrote that above. But the `>=today` does the same and it is less code. I do not see what can be faster about any of your variants.